# Flutter ListView Jumps To Top

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I am creating a news feed for my app and as I scroll down data is fetched from Firestore. As soon as I scroll up the listview literally snaps to the very top skipping all the other items in between. The listview works fine if I load it with static data but when i pull data from Firestore, the issue reemerges. I am not sure what's causing this behaviour.

[Video demonstrating the irregular scrolling behaviour](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GBXEOgGpPnh-0I60X9WBRSrbDfDmtcKF)

Here is my code

```
return StreamBuilder(
            stream: Firestore.instance.collection(Constants.NEWS_FEED_NODE)
                .document("m9yyOjsPxV06BrxUtHdp").
            collection(Constants.POSTS_NODE).orderBy("timestamp",descending: true).snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData)
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);

              if (snapshot.data.documents.length == 0)
                return Container();
              //after getting the post ids, we then make a call to FireStore again
              //to retrieve the details of the individual posts
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                  itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
                    return FeedItem2(feed: Feed.fireStore(
                        snapshot: snapshot.data.documents[index]),);
                  });
            },
          );
```

Comment: Can you replace `return FeedItem2()` with `return Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(50.0), child: Text("test"));` and see if the problem goes away? If so, it may point to `FeedItem2` widget being the issue in which case we would need to see the code for that widget. I assume that widget is doing something dynamic

Comment: For fun, try passing a `cacheExtent: 10000.0` to the ListView factory constructor. That might help us isolate if we are hitting issues with how ListView disposes and re-init's widgets as you scroll through what's currently visible

Comment: Perhaps ensuring that FeedItem2 is always the same height (on it's first render and any subsequent such as loading an image). As dynamically changing the height of an element in a list view can cause some off screen elements to initialize which in turns pushes them far enough out of view to be disposed.. I can't quite tell from the video if this could be the case. FWIW

Comment: For me the solution was combination of cacheExtent (any reasonable number of pixels) and shrinkWrap: false

Comment: @AshtonThomas the `cacheExtent` definitely helped with this issue, but it is also pretty memory intensive. Is there no other way around this issue? This seems like a major issue for Flutter apps.

Answer (score 8):

Reason for the problem:

> `ListView`, and `ScrollViews` in general, tend to dispose of the children that are not currently visible on the screen. When we try to scroll back to the child, the child is reinitialized from scratch. But in this case, our child is a FutureBuilder; re-initializing it creates a progress indicator again just for a part of a second, then creates the page once again. This confuses the scrolling mechanism, throwing us around in non-deterministic ways.

[Solution](https://medium.com/saugo360/flutter-creating-a-listview-that-loads-one-page-at-a-time-c5c91b6fabd3#a358):

> One way to solve this is to make sure that the progress indicator has the exact same size of the page, but in most cases, that is not too practical. So, we will resort to a method that is less efficient, but that will solve our problems; we will prevent ListView from disposing of the children. In order to do that, we need to wrap each child — that is, each `FutureBuilder`, with an `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`. This mixin makes the children ask their parent to keep them alive even when off-screen, which will solve our problem. So:

1. Replace the FutureBuilder in your code with KeepAliveFutureBuilder.
2. Create the KeepAliveFutureBuilder widget:

```
class KeepAliveFutureBuilder extends StatefulWidget {

  final Future future;
  final AsyncWidgetBuilder builder;

  KeepAliveFutureBuilder({
    this.future,
    this.builder
  });

  @override
  _KeepAliveFutureBuilderState createState() => _KeepAliveFutureBuilderState();
}

class _KeepAliveFutureBuilderState extends State<KeepAliveFutureBuilder> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: widget.future,
      builder: widget.builder,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

- This widget is just a wrapper around the FutureBuilder. It is a StatefulWidget whose State extends the State class with the AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin.
- It implements the wantKeppAlive getter, and makes it simply return true, to denote to the ListView that we want this child to be kept alive.

Comment: But with a very long list (think list od all emails you ever got) this is not really practical, is it? There is a reaaon why off-screen views are disposed of.

Comment: Agree. Imho. the best way is storing the image size and using this information to avoid the problem.

Comment: +1 This here solved my problem. I had a small list of vastly different sized widgets. With the KeepAliveFutureBuilder they load one time (if they are scrolled to) and are kept in memory. They reload as normal when the entire page and/or data is reloaded.

Answer (score 6):

Just had the same issue using Flutter 1.17.3. Based on the comment from @Ashton-Thomas here: [Flutter ListView Jumps To Top](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51536756/144857#comment90422606_51536756) I added:

```
cacheExtent: estimatedCellHeight * numberOfItems,
```

to my `ListView` constructor and the problem went away. It has drastically increased the responsiveness of the entire list as well.

Note: my list only has about 50 items in it, so the `cacheExtent` isn't extremely high. May need to adjust if you have hundreds/thousands of items.

Answer (score 6):

This problem has 2 solutions:

**Solution 1:** (If height of ListView is dynamic)

1. Wrap the `ListView` with `SingleChildScrollView`
2. Set the `physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` property of ListView as
   mentioned
3. Set `shrinkWrap: true` to avoid render issue

or

**Solution 2:** (If height of ListView is known or predictable)

- set `cacheExtent:` to the height of the ListView - It is a `double` value.
- Eg - If 10 items are present in ListView & each item has 20.0 as height, then give `cacheExtent: 200.0`

Comment: Adding NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() avoids scrolling, which is an anti-pattern I think!

Comment: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() should be used for the children when you use a ScrollView inside another ScrollView. In the above case where we are not sure about the height of the ListView elements, we should use the above solution of wrapping it with SingleChildScrollView(). That will solve the case as it will take ScrollController of the Parent and ignores the ListView's ScrollController. This will not snap the scroll to top everytime you scroll up.

Comment: Anhaa, i see, because it;s inside the SingleCh........ right?, why not put a Column inside SingleChi....... then? help me understand @SankarArumugam

Comment: @emanuel You can put column inside SingleChildScrollView. But the question here is to fix the issue while using ListView. So it's done like that

Comment: Anhaa, thanks for this

Comment: This solution worked great for my case, thanks!

Comment: Great answer. I would consider that a bug in ListView, with this as an unfortunate workaround necessity.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your top most widget in SingleChildScrollView().