# Flutter ListView with Streambuilders gets stuck when scrolling from bottom to top

Tags: listview, flutter

Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/Mike278/99cab86f3b908a06ae637b2d897b4a0c) to reproduce the issue [in this gif](https://gfycat.com/clumsyslowamericanratsnake). Even though the BehaviorSubject has the data available, [StreamBuilder still renders a no-data frame](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16465). This causes an issue when using StreamBuilders in a listview, specifically when scrolling from bottom to top as demonstrated. So far the suggested [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51536756/flutter-listview-jumps-to-top)(s) are to create a StreamBuilder whose State has an `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`, or increase the ListView's `cacheExtent` - both of which work but seem hacky. Does anyone have any other suggestions for dealing with this? Or is the `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` the best way to go.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you come across any solution?

Comment: I made the Loading Container have the same size as that of the List items and that solved the issue.